# converting excel worksheet function into vba

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I'm having trouble with the following macro. I'm trying to get the following function which works converted in VBA.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(time!$I$1418:time!$I$39433,--(time!$E$1418:time!$E$39433=$B11),--(time!$G$1418:time!$G$39433=E$2))
```

This is because that function slows Excel down too much if it exists in too many cells.

Here's what I got so far. I'm trying to loop from column c to the column where the second row = "total", then I go down the next row and I repeat the process until the cell in column B is blank.

I've got a run-time error 1004, application defined error or object-defined error and they are highlighting the sumproduct part.

```
Sub date_stats()

Dim first_cell As Integer
Dim time As Worksheet
Set time = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("time")
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, num As Integer

firstcell = Range("e65000").End(xlUp).Row + 1

Do Until ActiveSheet.Range("b" & firstcell).Value = ""
firstcell = firstcell + 1
i = 2
    Do Until ActiveSheet.Cells(2, i).Value = "total"
    i = i + 1

    num = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumProduct(time.Range("i2:i50000"), --(time.Range("E2:E50000") = ActiveSheet.Range("B" & first_cell)), --(time.Range("G2:G50000") = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 2)))

    Loop
Loop
```

**FIRST UPDATE**

I'm making progress. I forgot that I was using a different module and consequently did not have the options explicit put on the new module and that I was misspelling firstcell and first_cell. I've got all the bugs removed on the VBA but now the result that is coming up is #REF which means that it is referencing deleted cells which is clearly not the case. Here's the new updated workbook.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9zzW6-3m2qGeFNCdEhtem44Wnc/edit?usp=sharing

And here is the code:

```
Sub date_stats()


Dim first_cell As Integer
Dim time2 As Worksheet
Set time2 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("time")
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, num As Integer
Dim x As String
Dim y As String
Dim z As Range




'num = Format(num, "standard")


Application.ScreenUpdating = False


With ActiveSheet
first_cell = .Range("e65000").End(xlUp).Row


'=SUMPRODUCT(time!$I$1418:time!$I$39433,--(time!$E$1418:time!$E$39433=$B11),--(time!$G$1418:time!$G$39433=E$2))


Do Until .Range("b" & first_cell).Value = ""
first_cell = first_cell + 1
i = 3
    Do Until .Cells(2, i).Value = "total"

    x = .Range("B" & first_cell).Address
    y = .Cells(2, i).Address
    Set z = .Cells(first_cell, i)
    z.Value = Evaluate("=SUMPRODUCT(time2!$I$2:$I$50000,--(time2!$E$2:time2!$E$50000=" & x & "),--(time2!$G$2:time2!$G$50000=" & y & "))")
     i = i + 1
    Loop
Loop


End With


Application.ScreenUpdating = True




End Sub
```

Comment: Try bracketing the calculations of your macro with `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` and `Application.ScreenUpdating = True`

Comment: It's going to be a matter of breaking it down into simpler constituent parts until you isolate the problem.  Of course make sure the VBA compiles with `Option Explicit` at the top of the module.

Comment: `SumProduct` worksheet function is more limited in VBA as it doesn't support array arguments.  You can get around this by creating your range based on criteria first, and then pass in the range to `SumProduct`

Comment: could you give an example

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved.  I changed the name of the sheet time to time2 because time was already used by Excel as a special function.  But when I used the evaluation feature that was no longer necessary.

Evaluate("=SUMPRODUCT(Time!$I$2:$I$50000,--(Time!$E$2:$E$50000=" & x & "),--(Time!$G$2:$G$50000=" & y & "))")

So the problem was due to a typo.